# How to add a table in Nova Database : Openstack

Tags: sqlalchemy, models, openstack, openstack-nova

I'm adding one class nova.db.sqlalchemy.models to create associated table in Nova DB but its not reflecting there.

Doing same in neutron is creating a Table in Neutron DB.

Openstack documentation does not explains how to extend the database anywhere.
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/api/nova.db.sqlalchemy.models.html

How this issue can be resolved ?

Comment: i thought db transacations were now being done out of oslo's sqlalchmey classes.

Comment: I can't find any sqlalchemy classes under oslo.

Comment: common db have just one ModelBase class.
All the model definition classes are in nova.db.sqlalchemy.models only.

Comment: like this: 
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/database.html#the-nova-db-sqlalchemy-models-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would also have to add migration file in  nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions/, after that do 'nova-manage db sync'. The new table should be reflected now. HTH

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your model inside nova/db/sqlalchemy/models.py
2. Create [migration file](https://sqlalchemy-migrate.googlecode.com/files/sqlalchemy-migrate-doc-0.7.2.pdf) inside  nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions/ . 
    You can do this by simply adding a .py file with an increased version number
3. Provide **upgrade() and downgrade()** functions as described in this [pdf](https://sqlalchemy-migrate.googlecode.com/files/sqlalchemy-migrate-doc-0.7.2.pdf)
4. sync nova db using:

> nova-manage db sync